# Cannot open a file with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm following the same instruction as listed on this page 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7761153?login=true
and yet I cannot open this text file

```
tell application 

  "TextEdit" open file "Macintosh HD:Users:kylefoley:codes:byu_docs:dictionaries:first_name_research:btn_tree_start_r.rtxt" 

end tell
```

The error message I'm getting is: Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found class name.

Ultimately I need to be open it with a python script.  So when I use Python I get a different error message:

```
file='Macintosh HD:Users:kylefoley:codes:byu_docs:dictionaries:first_name_research:btn_tree_start_r:Jaxson.rtxt'



os.system(

...    f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 

...        'tell application 

...            "TextEdit" open file "{file}" 

...         end tell' ''')

/usr/bin/osascript: option requires an argument -- e

usage: osascript [-l language] [-e script] [-i] [-s {ehso}] [programfile] [argument ...]

sh: line 3: tell application 

            "TextEdit" open file "Macintosh HD:Users:kylefoley:codes:byu_docs:dictionaries:first_name_research:btn_tree_start_r:Jaxson.rtxt" 

         end tell: command not found
```

I should also add that I'm certain the file exists because when I put in a bogus file I get the following error message: No such file or directory

++++++++++++++++++
UPDATE
+++++++++++++++++

Ok, I can open it with Script Debugger but that's useless because I need to be able to execute the apple script with Python.  When I run

```
tell application "TextEdit"

    open file "Macintosh HD:Users:kylefoley:codes:byu_docs:dictionaries:first_name_research:btn_tree_start_r:Jaxson.rtxt"

end tell
```

On Script Debugger it works.  But the Python syntax:

```
os.system(

...    f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 

...        'tell application "TextEdit"

...             open file "{file}" 

...         end tell' ''')

/usr/bin/osascript: option requires an argument -- e

usage: osascript [-l language] [-e script] [-i] [-s {ehso}] [programfile] [argument ...]

sh: line 3: tell application "TextEdit"

             open file "Macintosh HD:Users:kylefoley:codes:byu_docs:dictionaries:first_name_research:btn_tree_start_r:Jaxson.rtxt" 

         end tell: command not found
```

Also, the following fails:

```
os.system(

...    f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit" open file "{file}" end tell' ''')

28:32: syntax error: Expected end of line but found command name. (-2741)

os.system(

...    f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit" open file "{file}" ' ''')

28:32: syntax error: Expected end of line but found command name. (-2741)
```

I know Python can use Applescript because the following works:

```
os.system(
    f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "TextEdit" to save (every window whose name is "{file}")' ''')
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a line break between `tell application` and `"TextEdit"`.

Comment: If all you're doing is opening a file in TextEdit, and you're using `os.system` anyway, don't bother with `osascript`.  Just use the unix `open` command: `open -e /file/path`. Simpler is always better.

Comment: That does not work with files ending in extension `rtxt`.  But I can see why you would recommend that I should have stated that I tried that in my OP.

Comment: What kind of file is an `rtxt`? The `-e` option of the `open` utility explicitly means to open the file in TextEdit, so it should work as long as it's a type of file that TextEdit can open.

Comment: rtxt = 'rich text'.  TextEdit could not open the file due to some strange bug.  That's the whole reason why I opened this thread, namely, to get around the fact that textedit could not open the file, well, it would take about one minute.  But it could open the file if it was in richtext format.  strange, but the programming for you.

Answer (score 0):

State what the Applescript is in the variable `script` such as:

```
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
file = 'hey_you.rtxt"
    script =  f'''
    tell application "TextEdit"
        open file "{file}"
    end tell
    '''
```

Then:

```
p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
...stdout, stderr = p.communicate(script)
```